# How to run in Red Dead Redemption 2?

Tags: ps4, red-dead-redemption-2

Am I the only one bashing X button to run and he doesn't move faster at all? I've eaten well so the stamina and health are full and holding X or tapping it won't make it run. I can't even pass the first mission that I have to follow a group because they're running faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some areas like your camp where movement speed is restricted to a rather slow walk. I suspect you were in such an area. Tapping X should work usually, both on foot and on your horse.

Answer (score -1):

Play in first person. Then you'll default to running with the left stick pushed fully forward. And it looks better.

Answer (score -4):

Press L3 to run
X is to crouch

Comment: Unless you've modified the default controls (and I don't know other schemes - I kept mine default), this is the exact opposite.